# Is the Drive Information folder important?

Tags: windows

I found a folder in may drive D that named "Drive Information" (just "Drive Information" not "System Volume Information"!).

It is hidden and I think system folder, and it has a file in it that named "wkNtFsLdf.dat" with blue color of name font (compressed) and it's size is 596 MB.

Can I delete it? Is it important? If I delete it, will it effect my drive or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder/file is not needed by Windows. Deleting it could cause issues with other programs that rely on it which could cause all manner of problems with your system so it's not exactly 100% safe to delete but I imagine you would be fine.

It appears the program that creates this file and folder is a file recovery software called [FinalData](http://www.finaldata.com/). If you have that installed and use it then deleting the folder will probably affect this software.

Comment: thanks but I don't have Finaldata on my PC (even I don't install it!!)  can I delete the folder?!

Comment: I'd say you are fine to delete it. Like I say above Windows itself doesn't require it. Maybe copy it to a USB or external hard drive before deleting it. That way if it does mess up something you could just copy it back.

Comment: No worries. Best of luck.